# python module level logging

Tags: python, logging

Can I use ContextFilters in python logging to change loglevels based on modulenames. So something like

```
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
  CMDID_cf="IAMTEST1"
  def __init__(self, CMDID1): 
  self.CMDID_cf=CMDID1

  def filter(self,record):
    record.CMDID=self.CMDID_cf
    return True

  def moduleFilter(self):
     //something like below//
     if(modulename=="something")
     setLevel(logging.ERROR)

  #MAIN
  **define logger**
  obj=ContextFilter()
  logging.addFilter(obj.modukeFilter)
```

In the python documentation I haven't really found out anything about this so any help pointing to this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate way, which is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial), is to use module-level loggers named with `__name__` and to then set their levels as desired in the logging configuration. There's no need to use a `Filter` for this.

Comment: Hi Vinay,I went through your complete documentation and I agree that its the best way to implement. But due to the existing stupid structure of logging in my application (which obviously I cant change and its quite extensively used throughout) I was trying to find out an alternative method. 
Please help me if the method I am suggesting to use leads me anywhere towards a good solution